# Java Get the position of a value using an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, position, find

I'm trying to get the position of the STX (0x02) from the byte array message below. If you see the message, it has 0x2 in a number of places but the only position I want is the STX one. I've been looping through it backwards using a for loop. I have to loop backwards btw. I've tried a number of ways but I'm having difficulty getting that position. One way I've tried but has not worked is, wherever a 0x2 is, and has elements of 3 or more between that and an ETX (0x3) in front of it get that position of that STX. But I'm doing something wrong because I keep on getting an error which I am having difficulty resolving. Can you please help?

EDIT: If there is a better way then my logic of finding that position (STX) by distinguishing it from the other 0x2, please can you provide that.

EDIT: I have to loop backwards as that is required by the instructions given to me.

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
    //Test 3:
    public String Test3(List<Byte> byteList) {
        //checking positions of the STX and ETX
        //looping through the array backwards
        for (int i = byteList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {                
            if (byteList.get(i) == STX && (i >= 3 && byteList.get(i) == ETX)) {
                STXpos = i;
            }
        }       
        return STXpos;
    }
    byte[] validMsgWithRandomData = {0x32,0x32,0x32, //Random data
    0x02, // STX
    0x31,0x32,0x10,0x02,0x33, // Data 31 32 02 33
    0x03, // ETX
    0x31^0x32^0x02^0x33^0x03,// LRC calculated from the data (with the DLE removed) plus the ETX
    0x2,0x3,0x00,0x02 //Random data
};
```

Comment: Please share the code you're using to loop through the array.

Comment: "I have to loop backwards btw." -> Why exactly? As to the core problem... there are some standard algorithms for finding a pattern within a text, like [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and [BM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)

Comment: How can both `byteList.get(i) == STX` be true as well as `byteList.get(i) == ETX` unless `STX == ETX`? are you missing  `i - something` on the STX test?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong , sorted Set should be better if you are working with position in the Collection

Comment: I think the position of this byte matters to the op. moving it to a different position by using a sorted set will kinda defeat the point. cause its location will depend on any other data in the set. In this case he could just use find.

Comment: Srinath Ganesh, Set allows for no repetition, but a message might have a valid 0x2 value besides the STX. So, I need to use list so that I can keep all 0x2 but still be able to locate the index of the STX.

Comment: Arnon Zilca, so you're suggesting that I am missing 'i - something', could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Kaal how many elements separate STX from ETX?

Comment: Arnon Zilca, the elements in between the STX and ETX can change any time, but normally it would be more than 3 or possibly 3. But that is why I am not sure if this is the logical way of locating the index of that STX position. It is just one way, and the only one I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the amount of elements between STX and ETX is not a constant, i'd search in normal order and look for ETX after I find STX:

```java
public String Test3(List<Byte> byteList) {
    // find potential STX
    for (int i = 0; i < byteList.size(); ++i) {
        if (byteList.get(i) == STX) {
            // make sure matching ETX exists
            for (int j = i + 1; j < byteList.size(); ++j) {
                if (byteList.get(j) == ETX) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do it in reverse order if you really want:

```java
public String Test3(List<Byte> byteList) {
    // find potential ETX
    for (int i = byteList.size() - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        if (byteList.get(i) == ETX) {
            // make sure matching STX exists
            for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; --j) {
                if (byteList.get(j) == STX) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

By the way if you want to *force* a distance of elements between STX and ETX you can do it by changing `j`'s initialization.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect. I can work around this now and experiment with looping backwards, and see what I get.

Comment: np. why would you like to loop backwards?

Comment: because I've been doing other tests of other message byte arrays and in one of them there are two messages (first message which is the old one and the one after that is the new one). The most recent one with the STX is the valid one and that is the second message, so looping backwards made sense to find the first stx position and it worked perfectly for that. But this was a whole different problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reverse version. I tried it but it comes to 11, which is the incorrect 0x2. Like your first version it should be index 3. When I replaced your j = i - 1 with j = i - 2, it gave me the second 0x2 (index 7) which is a bit closer to correct 0x2 (index 3) but entering anything more than 2 doesn't give me 3, it just keeps on giving me 7. Why is that?

Comment: No worries, it works with SR_'s backward loop solution (see below). I'll use that.

Answer (score 2):

My first attempt with backward loop and in O(n) complexity.

EDIT : getting rid of candidate for STX.

EDIT 2 : This solution works at least for a few cases including OP's one (but it has not been tested extensively...).

```
    final int NOTFOUND = -1;
    final int ETX = 0x03;
    final int STX = 0x02;
    int stxpos = NOTFOUND;
    int etxpos = NOTFOUND;
    int etxcandidatepos = NOTFOUND;
    for (int i = validMsgWithRandomData.length - 1; i >=0; --i)
    {
        if (ETX == validMsgWithRandomData[i])
        {
            etxcandidatepos = i;
            if (NOTFOUND == etxpos)
            {
                etxpos = i;
                stxpos = NOTFOUND;
            }
        }
        else if (STX == validMsgWithRandomData[i])
        {
            if (NOTFOUND != etxpos)
            {
                stxpos = i;
                if (NOTFOUND != etxcandidatepos)
                {
                    etxpos = etxcandidatepos;
                    etxcandidatepos = NOTFOUND;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```